APScheduler in a Python flask app to execute recurring tasks isn't working with Gunicorn
I'm a newbie with Python and flask in general and I'm trying to create (I think) a kind of basic project: I have a flask web app that makes requests every 12 hours to a certain API endpoint and stores the result in a PostgreSQL database.
I'm it works very well in development mode, but as soon as it's deployed to a Digital Ocean droplet with Ubuntu, I'm getting the following error (and there's no other error):
[2024-09-06 12:10:23 +0200] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 23.0.0
[2024-09-06 12:10:23 +0200] [1] [DEBUG] Arbiter booted
[2024-09-06 12:10:23 +0200] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (1)
[2024-09-06 12:10:23 +0200] [1] [INFO] Using worker: gevent
[2024-09-06 12:10:23 +0200] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
[2024-09-06 12:10:23 +0200] [1] [DEBUG] 1 workers
[2024-09-06 12:10:25 +0200] [1] [ERROR] Worker (pid:8) exited with code 3
[2024-09-06 12:10:25 +0200] [1] [ERROR] Shutting down: Master
[2024-09-06 12:10:25 +0200] [1] [ERROR] Reason: Worker failed to boot.

This is my docker-compose.yml file:
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command:
      [
        "gunicorn",
        "-k",
        "gevent",
        "-b",
        "0.0.0.0:5000",
        "app:create_app()",
        "--log-level",
        "debug",
      ]
    environment:
      ENABLE_SCHEDULER: ${ENABLE_SCHEDULER}
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - fullstack

  db:
    container_name: scrape-jobs-db
    image: postgres:16.4-alpine3.20
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./init-db.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init-db.sh
      - ./.env:/app/.env
    networks:
      - fullstack

I'm not sure this is the most interesting part of __init__.py but here it is:
if os.getenv("ENABLE_SCHEDULER", "true"):
        print("Scheduler IS enabled.")
        scheduler = GeventScheduler()
        scheduler.add_job(
            next_run_time=datetime.now(),
            func=scheduled_job,
            trigger="interval",
            hours=12,
            args=[app],
            max_instances=3,
        )
        scheduler.start()
    else:
        print("Scheduler is NOT enabled.")

I have tried using BackgroundScheduler() but I'm still getting the same result.
Am I doing something else wrong? Is there anything else I should check?
NOTE: I'm not doing anything aysnc or similar, nor am I using request. I'm just using this library for scraping content.

This is APScheduler and not Flask-APScheduler?

Also see this. I'm not quite sure how you've determined that this error is from APScheduler itself from those logs unless you have it running on a cron-like timer and you notice that it always coincides with that time

@roganjosh I've changed it for Flask-APScheduler and I'm getting EXACTLY the same error. Also, I don't now if the error is related to APScheduler to be honest, although I'm guessing it isn't because if I pass the environment variable ENABLE_SCHEDULER=false I'm still getting the same error

The fact that a thread/process can't start needs further investigation. It's been many years since I looked into this stuff but APScheduler, in either incarnation, should not kill a process before it starts. I'd look into enhanced logging of gunicorn

@roganjosh unfortunately adding gunicorn logging hasn't changed the error output one bit
